# $xy=\ln (x+y)$ implies that $y=\frac{\ln x}{x}+O(\frac{\ln x}{x^3}), x\to+\infty$.

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, implicit-differentiation

> $xy=\ln (x+y)$ implies that $y=\frac{\ln x}{x}+O(\frac{\ln x}{x^3}), x\to+\infty$.

How to prove it? Even the easiest part $\lim_{x\to+\infty}y=0$ I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $\, x y = \ln(x+y)\,,$ then it is
symmetric in $x$ and $y$. Thus, assume that
$\,0<y<x.\,$ This implies that $\,y < \ln(2x)/x\,$
and also $\, y\to +0$ as $x\to+\infty.\,$ Now
$$ x y = \ln(x(1+xy/x^2)) = \ln(x) +
\ln(1+\ln(x+y)/x^2). \tag1 $$
But, $\,\ln(x+y)\to \ln(x)\,$ as $\,x\to+\infty\,$ since $\, y\to 0$ as $x\to+\infty\,$
and $\,\ln(1+z)\to z\,$ as $\,z\to 0.\,$
Thus,
$\,y = \frac{xy}x = \frac{\ln(x)}x + O\Big(\frac{\ln(x)}{x^3}\Big).$

Comment: $y$ depends on $x$ so $\ln (x+y)$ need not be asymptotically equal to $\ln (x)$.

Comment: @BrunoKrams You may be right in general, but at least here we have $y\to0$ and also $y' = \frac{1-y(x+y)}{-1+x(x+y)} \to 0$, and then with l'Hospital, $\lim\frac{\log x}{\log(x+y)} = \lim\frac{x+y}{x(1+y')} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$x y=\log(x+y)$$
then
$$y=-x-\frac 1x \,W_{-1}\left(-x\,e^{-x^2} \right)$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Use the expansion given in the linked page
$$W_{-1}(t)= L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(-t)$ and $L_2=\log(-L_1)$.